# Creating Multiple Objects in a Loop Issue

Tags: java, loops, object

I need to create multiple objects in a loop. I read elsewhere that adding them into a list would accomplish this task, but the below code gives me a set of copies of the same object, i.e. all with the same values. Any idea how I can create multiple objects, rather than just copies of the same one? Thank you.

(The code below is a simplified version of what I'm working on)

```
    System.out.println("Creating swarm of size "+swarmSize);
    List<Dog> myDogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();

    for(int i = 0; i < dogAmount; i++) {
        System.out.println("New Dog # "+i);
        myDogs.add(new Dog(i));
    }

    Dog first = myDogs.get(0);
    Dog other = myDogs.get(3);
    System.out.println(first.getID()+" "+other.getID());
    //prints out the number of dogs I should have created -1 both times
```

My Dog class

```
import java.util.*;

public class Dog{
    public static int dogID;

    public Dog(int ID) {
        dogID = ID;
    }

    public int getID() {
    return dogID;
    }

    public void setID(int id) {
        dogID = id;     
    }
}
```

Comment: could you paste the code for class Dog please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
public static int dogID;
```

to

```
public int dogID;
```

or better yet,

```
private int dogID;
```

since you have a getter function for it, so other classes don't need to access the field directly.

Answer (score 1):

You're using:

```
public static int dogID;         //STATIC is the issue
```

Which means that all dogs have the same dogID, try to remove 'static' and it will work. (Every dog will have a unique ID).